# Using spring-cloud-integration without spring-boot

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am interested in using `spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka` without spring boot, as I have an existing in container application that uses Jersey servlets and other custom code.

Is there any straight forward way to enable the same functionality I get from annotating a spring-boot application with `@EnableBinding` with an in container app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnableBinding` is a general Spring Configuration, so in principle it can be used outside Spring Boot applications, just by adding it to a configuration class. Make sure you do include a binder on the classpath.

That being said, you can still package your Spring Boot application (using `@EnableBinding`) as a WAR and run it in your servlet container. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging